# Are we ready to step out of bootstrap mode?

Tags: discussion

*UPDATE: And we're launched!*

---

I think our little community here is doing pretty darn well. Thanks everyone for your awesome involvement!

Are we ready to get out of bootstrap mode? I think this will help increase the quality of tags and other elements that make SSD what it is. On the other hand, it can be pretty frustrating as a new user, especially if you want to vote or write a comment. This is why I have been so reluctant to do so.

**What is Bootstrap Mode?**

Bootstrap Mode helps to shape the community while it grows. Reputation requirements are relaxed, which means that users can do just about anything regardless of their reputation.

**Check out what points you need to do what once out of Bootstrap Mode:**

- New users can ask and answer
  questions, which is how they
  start earning rep points.
- 15   Vote up
- 15   Flag offensive
- 50  Leave comments
- 100 Vote down (costs 1 rep), edit
  community wiki posts
- 250 Vote to close or reopen your
  questions, create new tags
- 500 Retag questions
- 2000    Edit other people's posts
- 3000    Vote to close or reopen any
  questions
- 10000   Delete closed questions, access
  to moderation tools

For more info check out the FAQ: https://sound.stackexchange.com/faq

**Vote up if you want us to get out of Bootstrap Mode.**

Kudos to all for being part of such a fantastic little community! Thank you!

:-)

*P.S. it's under "community wiki" so we don't get points when up-voted.*

Comment: Oh yes, let's do it! It is only fair to do it after more than a year of free speech for everyone... The high-to-very-high-reputation "skills" are not essential to users participation in the discussions. Let's get serious!

Comment: Excellent! Such great work, Andrew...

Answer (score 9):

Firstly, well done Andrew on creating this awesome community!

I definitely think SSD has grown very well. It's not difficult for new users to gain reputation points as long as the whole community does use the voting system. I often see very interesting posts that don't receive any votes. It's not that we want to be the one with most points, but I think it is a great way to judge the popularity and general feelings about a post.

Comment: I totally agree. We need to all vote more :-) Not quite sure how to get people to vote more. For users with under 200 points, I have a little note at the top of questions to ask them to vote. Hopefully getting them into the habit.    

Comment: Seconded and appropriately upvoted.

Comment: What about advertising the voting system? A promotion/tutorial video could explain why it's here, how it may be used, what it translates to...

Answer (score 6):

YES.

We are ready.

Bring it on.

**:-)**

Comment: It's easy for you to say Mr. +10K points ;-)

Comment: @Andrew Hey hey I'm just sayin'. :)

Comment: You're such a showoff...

Comment: Why not. Got to get there sometime.

Answer (score 1):

One request for the developers: this site doesnt work well on my iPad - as soon as I start entering text, the display scrolls back to the top of the page so that you cannot see what you are typing...

Comment: Similar problem on the iPhone....  I seem to remember someone mentioning something about developing an app, even did a screenshot.  Whatever happened to that?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've been away with limited Internet. This issue used to happen on my iPhone and my iPad, but now it doesn't anymore. Have you updated to the latest OS?